# Crashlytics errors in logcat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

Android app version: 1.0.52

Device: Moto G 2014

When looking at the logcat after the Android app crashes I have noticed the following in it.

```
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/android/apps/com.stackexchange.marvin/settings
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): com.crashlytics.android.internal.aD: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.b(SourceFile:1391)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.f(SourceFile:1664)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.d(SourceFile:1576)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.c(SourceFile:1590)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aO.a(SourceFile:63)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:48)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aW.a(SourceFile:36)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aS.c(SourceFile:125)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:884)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics.a(SourceFile:54)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.t.a(SourceFile:839)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.aa.run(SourceFile:13)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to settings.crashlytics.com/127.0.0.1 (port 443) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:131)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:143)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:226)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at com.crashlytics.android.internal.ay.a(SourceFile:1912)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): ... 10 more
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
12-25 21:54:40.641 E/Crashlytics(14236): ... 25 more
```

So does that mean the crashes aren't being automatically reported unless I submit the one via Google?

Comment: A crash reporting system that crashes ? Crash-ception. And yes, looks like no bug reports are being sent due to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your device is routing settings.crashlytics.com to localhost.  According to [this answer from Hemal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24611412/860000), it was probably caused by an ad blocker.

As you surmised, this does mean we aren't getting your crash reports so you could send with Google (unless that is blocked too).